# Parsing Json array to get a value

Tags: json, parsing, jenkins, jq

I have a nested JSON file:

```js
{
    "SupportedVersions": [
        {
            "EKSVersion": "1.13",
            "ContainerVersions": [
                "0.0.62",
                "0.0.63",
                "0.0.73",
                "0.0.75",
                "0.0.77"
            ]
        },
        {
            "EKSVersion": "1.14",
            "ContainerVersions": [
                "0.0.62",
                "0.0.63",
                "0.0.66",
                "0.0.67",
                "0.0.68",
                "0.0.69",
                "0.0.70",
                "0.0.71",
                "0.0.72",
                "0.0.73",
                "0.0.74",
                "0.0.75",
                "0.0.79"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get the last version of Container Versions from the file. I used the jq:

```bsh
cat *.json | jq '.ContainerVersions[length + 1].ContainerVersions[-length]'
```

But can't use it from jenkins so need some other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted to get the last item of the `SupportedVersions` array and the last item of its `ContainerVersions` array, just use a negative index. Negative indices will index relative to the end of the array, rather than the start.

```
.SupportedVersions[-1].ContainerVersions[-1]
```